# Process unstructured and multiple line CSV in hadoop

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, opencsv

I would like to process data in Hadoop Mapreduce, I am having data below format with unstructured, multiple line and un-terminated quotations.

```
    2/1/2013 5:16,Edward Felton,2,8/1/2012 3:57,Working on all the digital elements for our big event in Sydney in a couple of weeks... for more visit http://www.xy.com/au/geworks/,324005862,2,18200695
    12/28/2012 19:28,Laura McCullum,2,7/26/2012 18:03,"The Day You Give Them Jive  <br>
<a href="http://youtu.be/qfq9LVD2Qr4" > http://youtu.be/qfq9LVD2Qr4 <br>
 <br>
'Like' if you have always wanted to destroy a cube!",502114904,2,18400313
    11/21/2012 13:35,Timothy Widdowson,4,8/17/2012 12:38,"Can a table really replace a laptop...

With the new Windows tablets on the horizon and the Apple / Android devices out there I have been wondering if it is possible to really work with just and tablet. 

My mission:
-For one whole week I will be working with just my iPad. 

Hardware:
-Apple iPad
-Apple keyboard.
-Apple to HDMI connector.
-HDMI capable monitor.
- InCase iPad stand.

:-)",105001439,1,19301609
    3/15/2013 13:43,Mary Romeo,3,8/16/2012 22:23,"HOW TO SHORTEN LONG LINKS YOU'RE POSTING <br>
The attached image describes how to shorten a long url before posting it.  In 4 easy steps the 3-4 line urls can become a tiny link to post.",213022329,1,19901561
    11/30/2012 2:17,Lu Yin Zhong,3,8/29/2012 1:29,working on 2013 comms plan...need big ideas!!,302014449,2,20300666
    3/5/2013 22:15,Tim Steigert,12,8/29/2012 15:36,"Looking up 1024 email addresses. Manually? Probably a day! Doing it with SSOget, the add-in for  #[&quot;excel&quot;]? 5 minutes! Effort saved and  #[&quot;productivity&quot;] gained? Priceless! Now go get it and enjoy it for yourself! :)<br>http://sc.xy.com/*SSOget @@@data@@@{&quot;image&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;&quot;}",100011871,11,20400713
    11/1/2012 20:46,Pranay Jain,2,8/30/2012 14:26,Do people agree with the iCloud restrictions that Airwatch will put on Personal iOS devices that have email?,212065316,0,20700913
    11/9/2012 18:32,Monica Sharma,5,9/7/2012 11:42,hhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh gh gh gh gh ghghghghgghhhghghghghgh hg h gh gh,502000192,5,21400516
```

Please provide me code snippet how to handle mentioned data ?
Thanks in advance!!!!!!!

Comment: "process" can mean many things.  What are you trying to do and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're coping with multi-line data you cannot use a simple `TextInputFormat` to access your data. Thus you need to use a custom `InputFormat` for CSV files.

Currently there is no built-in way of processing multi-line CSV files in Hadoop (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2208), but luckily there's come code on github you can try: https://github.com/mvallebr/CSVInputFormat.

As far as the non-terminated quotations is concerned, it might be necessary to pre-process the data and clean it up in the first place. One simple rule would be to escape the quotations if there is no separator before or after the quotation (`"`):

- escape: `a"b` => `a\"b`
- leave unchanged: `a;"b` and `a";b`

Another option would be correcting the application that produces invalid CSV to escape the data in a proper way.